# Powershell Padding SecureString input

Tags: powershell

The code I am using now:

```
$password=Read-Host -Prompt "Enter password" -AsSecureString
```

So, if the entered password is less than 16 characters, how do I pad the secure string to make sure that the entered password is total of 16 characters, without converting back to plain text.

**[Edit]**

Well, when I enter my password in an online banking website using AES encryption, I noticed that the number of characters of my password gets increased to a certain count before they log me in as was indicated by the number of special character '*' in the password field. So, I suspected that same process might be possible in powershell too.

**[Edit]**

Turns out, they weren't actually actually appending the password. They were simply replacing the password with other junk number of characters so that the password will be removed from the browser just after clicking login.

**[Solution]**

SecureString has an in-built method `AppendChar([Char] $char)` which adds the $char to the securestring as below:

```
$password.Appendchar('a') #adds 'a' to the securestring.
```

It does decode the securestring first and appends the character , but it also cleans the decoded string from the memory as soon as the result is converted back to the securestring. so, it is safe to use `AppendChar()` .

Comment: You don't.  That defeats the point of a SecureString.  You'll need to do BSTR marshalling or create a `[PSCredential]` object to reverse the password.

Comment: Well, when I enter my password in an online banking website using AES encryption, I noticed that the number of characters of my password gets increased to a certain count before they log me in as was indicated by the number of special character '*' in the password field. So, I suspected that same process might be possible in powershell too.

Comment: They probably aren't padding the password, they are most likely replacing it with a fixed amount of characters ( https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/44912/why-do-some-websites-increase-the-number-of-characters-in-the-password-field-whe )

Comment: Right @Owain Esau .

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 I guess I will have to do the BSTR marshalling then.

Comment: Hello @TheIncorrigible1 , I have provided a solution. So kindly remove the downvote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[Solution]**

The below chain of inbuilt-commands provided for SecureString type simply solved the above requirement:

```
$secureString=Read-Host -Prompt "Enter the string" -AsSecureString
$secureStringth.Appendchar('a') #appends character 'a' to the securestring.
```

This was confirmed by displaying the characters in plaintext using a custom built cmdlet which I called as `Decode-SecureString.ps1` :

```
param([SecureString]$SecureString)
               Write-Information -MessageData "Retrieving string..." -Verbose -InformationAction Continue
                    try{
                    $bstr = [Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($secureString)
                    $length = [Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::ReadInt32($bstr, -4)
                    [Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringBSTR($bstr)
                    }
                    finally{
                        if ( $bstr -ne [IntPtr]::Zero ) {
                          [Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::ZeroFreeBSTR($bstr)
                        }
                    }
```

Example:

```
$secureString=Read-Host -Prompt "Enter the string" -AsSecureString
Enter the string: *********
.\decode-securestring.ps1 -securestring $secureString
Retrieving string...
123456789
$secureString.Appendchar('a')
.\decode-securestring.ps1 -securestring $secureString
Retrieving string...
123456789a
```

As we can see, the secure string was padded with a character. And we can pad more number of characters as per our need.

Answer (score -1):

Best to just check the length of the password in a loop:

```
do {
    $password = [string](Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter a password ( atleast 16 digits ) ' -AsSecureString) 
    if ($password.Length -le 16) {
        Write-Host "not enough characters"
        continue
    }
    break
} while ($true)
```

Padding a password is not a good idea.

Comment: Right. I will check for other solutions.

Comment: Hello @Owain Esau , I have provided a solution. So kindly remove the downvote. And, I didn't downvote your solution either.